# systemctl still asking for password even with sudoers

Tags: sudo, visudo

My **/etc/sudoers**

```
josh ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart servicename.service
```

running **systemctl restart servicename.service** still asks for password.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Running command: **locate systemctl**
shows it located here: /usr/bin/systemctl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just being in the `/etc/sudoers` file doesn't give you automatic `root` privileges all the time, as you seem to believe.  You must preface the commands you wish to run as `root` with "`sudo`", like `sudo systemctl restart servicename.service`. Without the `sudo`, `systemctl` runs as your unprivileged `$USER`, and you are prompted for your password. Reread `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: you're right, it works.. all I had to do was add sudo in the beginning. Clumsy mistake. time wasted :-P